# javascript in partial view not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

i have a little challenge with my javascript getting to my partial view. Any help will be highly appreciated
this is my code:

This is the controller code for the partial View. (from a controller called searchController)

```
 public PartialViewResult PdfPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

this is the code that opens the partial view

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("View pdf", "PdfPartialView", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "pdfContainer" })
```

And this is the partial view code:

```
 @model dynamic
<h4>Partial View That display PDF....</h4><br/>
<embed src="C:/Users/ionyejekwe/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/OnlineSearchLagos/OnlineSearchLagos/assets/img/gtb.pdf" width="1300" height="600" type="application/pdf"></embed>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //parent.document.location.reload();
        alert('hello');
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

the javascript code is not being triggered.
Please how do i go about this?

Comment: Could you share the HTML that is being rendered?

Comment: Please what html are you talking about?

Comment: When you run the page in the browser, that HTML

Comment: it render this page:  @model dynamic
<h4>Partial View That display PDF....</h4><br/>
<embed src="C:/Users/ionyejekwe/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/OnlineSearchLagos/OnlineSearchLagos/assets/img/gtb.pdf" width="1300" height="600" type="application/pdf"></embed>

but it does not trigger the script. the page is meant to display a pdf file, then close after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your script section from the partial view in the view you are loading the partial.

Comment: I wnt the script to be triggered in the partial view. moving the script did not work

Comment: When you render partial view into some parent View it becomes a part of the document (generated HTML). You are using document ready function, so there is no such thing like 'document ready triggered from partial view'. It is triggered when the document, (which also contains HTML from the partial view), is loaded completely. This script tag is usually located at the bottom of the parent view. jQuery must be included above it, so it might cause you errors too.

Answer (score 0):

With the info you provided, it's probably because you have your script inside `$(document).ready()`.

What you're doing here is binding an Ajax call to an ActionLink. Completed Ajax calls won't trigger a separate ready event for `document`, so that script will not execute this way.

Something you could do is define a self-calling function;

```
<script>
    (function(){
        //parent.document.location.reload();
        alert('hello');
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
        }, 5000);
   })();
</script>
```

Or, depending on the purpose of the script, put it in a function and bind that to the [`OnSuccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions.OnComplete) event of the Ajax call.